# reactjs & woocommerce rest api - add item to cart with selected options' value

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working on a react frontend for a woocommerce shop and I am currently trying to add an item to the cart with the selected option values ie size and color.

My current api call -

```
const AddToCart = async (id) => {
    let config = {
    method: "post",
    url: "/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item",
    data: {
      id : id,
      quantity: 1,
      attributes: [
        {
        color: color
        },
        {
        size: size
     }]
    }
    }
   const resp = await axios(config).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
  }
```

In the [docs](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks/blob/trunk/src/StoreApi/docs/cart.md#add-item) it says -

> Chosen attributes (for variations) containing an array of objects with
> keys attribute and value

However what I've tried is giving me this error -

```
code: "woocommerce_rest_variation_id_from_variation_data"
data: {status: 400}
message: "No matching variation found."
```

Example json response for single product -

```
   {
        "id": 933,
        .......    
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Size",
                "position": 0,
                "visible": false,
                "variation": true,
                "options": [
                    "2XL",
                    "3XL",
                    "4XL",
                    "5XL",
                    "L",
                    "M",
                    "S",
                    "XL",
                    "XS"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "default_attributes": [],
        "variations": [
            936,
            937,
            938,
            939,
            940,
            941,
            942,
            943,
            944
        ],
      ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the data like this:

```js
data: {
    id: id,
    quantity: 1,
    variation: [
        {
            attribute: "color"
            value: color,
        },
        {
            attribute: "size"
            value: size,
        }
    ]
}
```

As per documentation, variation accepts the array of objects and objects should have keys `attribute` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with this
[{ attribute: 'color', value : selectedColor  },{ attribute : 'size',  value : selected }]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).